# TypeScript compiler doesn't recognize check for optional object attribute in external function

Tags: typescript, validation, error-handling, optional-chaining

I have a type definition with an optional member which I need to access in a function. In order to assure that the optional member is indeed set, I created a "validator"-function which throws an error if the optional member of the object is not set. However, the TypeScript transpiler still complains that the optional member may be undefined when accessing it. When I check the member in the function directly, it sure recognizes the check.

Usually, I wouldn't mind that much, but since I have to check for lots of optional members, the code gets quite messy and I would like to extract the checks into a function. Also, when throwing an error inside the try-block, it is recommended to use an external error handler function instead of catching locally, but this will lead to the same problem: The TypeScript compiler not recognizing that the optional member's existence has been checked.

I have created a minimal code example which you can also test out in the [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgeQEYCsIGNgBVzQC8UA3gFBRQBOEAjgK4CWNAJgLIQKoRUBcUqOHAA2EAIYA7ANwUocMMEZwJY4Ry48A-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)

```js
type SomeObjectType = {
  requiredMember: boolean;
  optionalMember?: OptionalMemberType;
}

type OptionalMemberType = {
  someMember: string;
}

function main(someObject: SomeObjectType) {
  try {
    checkOptionalMemberSet(someObject);

    // if (!someObject.optionalMember) {
    //   throw new Error('Optional member not set, aborting...');
    // }

    console.log(someObject.requiredMember);
    console.log(someObject.optionalMember.someMember); // 'someObject.optionalMember' is possibly 'undefined'.(18048)
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}

function checkOptionalMemberSet(someObject: SomeObjectType) {
  if (!someObject.optionalMember) {
    throw new Error('Optional member not set, aborting...');
  }
}

const someObject = {
  requiredMember: true
};

main(someObject);
```

Any ideas what I could be missing here?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75016808/typescript-compiler-doesnt-recognize-check-for-optional-object-attribute-in-ext#comment132382059_75016808) For your specific code: https://tsplay.dev/wjXM1m

Comment: Thanks @TobiasS. & @jsejcksn, the `asserts` signature really helps for this (y)